# Update div:after property using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I need to update the following CSS using JQuery since the color will be generated dynamically. Any help will be appreciated:

```css
#Level1 div:after {
    content: "";  
    border-left-color: lightblue;
}
```

Here I need to update the border-left-color property dynamically so I have to use JQuery to update it.

Comment: pseudo elements are *not* part of the DOM, so you can't access it from script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery cannot directly select a pseudo element. What you can do instead is add a class to a parent element and then key the pseudo selector on that class, something like this:

```css
#Level1 div:after {
    content: "";  
    border-left-color: lightblue;
}
#Level1 div.foo:after {
    border-left-color: #C00;
}
```

```js
// add the class as needed in your JS code:
$('#Level1 div').addClass('foo');
```

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan for the answer. But how will I set the color property dynamically to the newly created class? please help.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to set the `border-left-color` property dynamically on `#Level1 div::after` in javascript (and in jQuery). Here's the jQuery solution: `var newStyles = '<style>#Level1 div::after {content: \'\'; border-left-color: lightblue;}</style>'; $('head').append(newStyles);` You can computationally manipulate the string `newStyles` prior to appending it.

Comment: Ok, maybe impossible was a little strong. However that method of doing anything is frankly horrendous